# reindex an object so keys are sequential

Tags: php, laravel, object, indexing, collections

I am building an object from a laravel collection, the code for this looks like this,

```
$project->briefNotifications = $user->notifications->filter(function($notification) use($project){
            if($notification->object_type == "brief" || $notification->object_type == "briefversion" && $notification->is_read == 0 && $notification->parent_id == $project->id) {
                $project->calendarAlerts++;
                return $notification;
            }
        });
```

This filters through the collection and returns an object that looks like this,

`0: {id: 7283, type: "create", activity: "Stephen saved a new version of the brief",…}
1: {id: 7282, type: "create", activity: "Stephen saved a new version of the brief",…}
2: {id: 7281, type: "create", activity: "Stephen saved a new version of the brief",…}
3: {id: 7280, type: "create", activity: "Stephen saved a new version of the brief",…}
5: {id: 7224, type: "update", activity: "Stephen changed Version 2 of the brief",…}`

I have a problem that I need sequential keys in my object - is this possible?

I know if my object were an array then I would be able to do,

`array_values($array)`

but I know of nothing similar in php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically all `array_*` functions are also available on Laravel's Collection class, as can be found [in the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#available-methods).

As you say you would normally do this using `array_values`, so all you have to do now is chain the call to `filter` with a call to `values`:

```
$project->briefNotifications = $user->notifications->filter(...)->values();
```